# cut substring with regular expression

Tags: regex, ant

I want to extract branch or tag information of my subversion URL with a regular expression.

http://192.168.1.6:8080/svn/main_repository/myCompany/myProject/branches/1.0 extract:

```
branches-1.0
```

http://192.168.1.6:8080/svn/main_repository/myCompany/myProject/tags/1.0.0 extract:

```
tags-1.0.0
```

Note I also want to replace the "/" by "-". I'm want to extract this in an ant script using the propertregex task like

```
<propertyregex property="svn.Branch" input="${svn.URL}" regexp="/myproject/([^/]+)" select="\1"/>
```

but this extracts only

```
branches
```

and

```
tags
```

What do I need to change to get the results above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more capture group to map version number

```
<propertyregex property="svn.Branch" input="${svn.URL}" regexp="/myproject/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" select="\1-\2"/>
```